# Recursion- finding consecutive counts of 1 in binary representation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary

I started to learn recursion and tried to solve the following problem:
Problem statement:
Need to find count of consecutive in binary number:

> Example:
>
> > The binary representation of 13 is 1011 , so the maximum number of
> >     consecutive 1's is 2.

I achieved the above one with the help of while loop.  However, I tried to achieve the solution via recursion but facing issue:

With While Loop:

```
int counter = 0, max =0, n=13;
    while (n > 0) {
        int rem = n%2;
        if (rem==1) counter++; 
        else counter=0;
        max = Math.max(counter, max);
        n/=2;
    }
    System.out.println(max);

Result : 2
```

Recursion :

```
public static int returnCount(int n,int count,int max){

        if (n > 0){
            int temp=n%2;
            if(temp==1)
                count++;
            else
                count=0;

            n/=2;
            max=Math.max(count,max);
            returnCount(n,count,max);           
        }
        return max;
    }
```

**Result: 1**

Please help me correcting my mistake in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the recursive call to *returnCount*, you never use the value it returned. In your solution, if *n* is odd, *returnCount* always returns 1 because the returned values of the recursive calls to *returnCount* are never used.

```
public static int returnCount(int n, int count, int max) {
    if (n > 0){
        if(n % 2 == 1)
            count++;
        else
            count = 0;
        n /= 2;
        max = Math.max(count, max);
        max = returnCount(n, count, max);           
    }
    return max;
}
```

To demonstrate my point, I'll trace through the code a little. If we run the following call to your code:

```
int answer = returnCount(13, 0, 0);
```

We end up with the following method calls:

1. `returnCount(13, 0, 0)`
2. `returnCount(6, 1, 1)`
3. `returnCount(3, 0, 1)`
4. `returnCount(1, 1, 1)`
5. `returnCount(0, 2, 2)`

During the iteration on the fourth call, *count* is incremented to 2 and *max* is assigned the value of 2 because *count* > *max*. By the fifth call, the answer is found and *max* remains to be 2.

However, when returning from the first call, the local variable *max* is still assigned 1. And the correct answer to our problem is lost because it was never returned from the fourth and fifth calls in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,you return **max** in the last of the recursion method. This line will executed for **N** times where **N** is how many times the **recursion method is being called**

If we store **max** value in a stack for every time recursion call, we will get all the value from stack from **return** line. But you will receive only the first value (**either 0 or 1**) of max which was calculated from first call(as it will execute at last).

So,do not return **max** from recursion as **max** changes for every call. just use **max** as global variable and **max** will be your answer.